# Powershell Script to swap Proxyaddresses and PrincipalName

Tags: powershell, active-directory, microsoft-exchange

Been writing script:

```
foreach ($Username in (Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\...\nope.csv")) {

    set-aduser $Username.Username -remove @{Proxyaddresses="smtp:$Username.Username@domain.com"}
        Write-Output "remove proxy"
    set-aduser $Username.Username -replace @{userPrincipalName="$Username.Username@domain.com"}
        Write-Output "replace principal"
    set-aduser $Username.Username -add @{Proxyaddresses="smtp:$Username.Username@domain.com"}
        Write-Output "add proxy"

}
```

the code runs but ends up putting this garbage -> @{Username=###}.Username@domain.com
in the attribute Editor.

Any help would be appreciated, been trying different ways for like 8h now.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon you should make that an answer and explain the difference.

Comment: so it should be: set-aduser $($Username.Username) -remove @{Proxyaddresses="smtp:$($Username.Username)@serpeandrews.com"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the double-quotes are expanding the object `$UserName` however are not allowing you to *reference* the property `UserName` of your object. An easy way to get around this is to use the [`Subexpression operator $( )`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#subexpression-operator--):

```
$object = [pscustomobject]@{
    Hello = 'World!'
}

$object.Hello      # => World!
"$object.Hello"    # => @{Hello=World!}.Hello
"$($object.Hello)" # => World!
```

On the other hand, a much easier solution in this case would be to reference the `UserName` property while enumerating the collection:

```
foreach ($UserName in (Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\...\nope.csv").UserName) {
    $upn = "$UserName@newDomain.com"
    Set-ADUser $UserName -Remove @{ ProxyAddresses = "smtp:$UserName@currentDomain.com" }
    Write-Output "Remove ProxyAddresses for $UserName"
    Set-ADUser $UserName -Replace @{ userPrincipalName = $upn }
    Write-Output "Replace UserPrincipalName for $UserName"
    Set-ADUser $UserName -Add @{ ProxyAddresses = "smtp:$upn" }
    Write-Output "Add ProxyAddresses for $UserName"
}
```

Comment: Wow! thanks a lot Santiago! I had to read it a few time to understand but that works awesome!